# Wordpress Page design is not loading

Tags: wordpress, apache, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a project and I had some problems uploading it. Now the problem is that all the pages looks like without format, a big white screen with the html, but nothing about the theme. I don´t know what happens because this appeared when my teacher (server owner) changed this values of the server to help me to use post name permalinks:

**My teacher changes in etc/apache2/apache2.conf  "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
And he did "sudo a2enmod rewrite" before restart apache.**

After that my theme stop working and you can see like that:

[image]

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your stylesheet and js URL. It is still loading from localhost. Update the database with new live URL

Comment: Yes, i saw that there is some data of localhost but i didnt know where to change it, I will take a look to the database.

Comment: Open your SQL file in any editor(use notepad++) and use find and replace method(Ctrl+F). Then replace "http://localhost/wordpress" with your new URL.

Comment: OMG, thanks man, I feel so stupid. I changed urls in database and works. I don´t know why this was working before my teacher server changes.